# How do i get this timer type of video player in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Newbie here. When I click the start button as like in the first image, I want to be able to get that player sort of thing with timer and everything. But how do I get this? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5kJU.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNLcY.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding [this](https://pub.dev/packages/circular_countdown_timer) plugin and use it like this :

```
Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: Center(
        child: CircularCountDownTimer(
          // Countdown duration in Seconds
          duration: 10,

          // Width of the Countdown Widget
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,

          // Height of the Countdown Widget
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,

          // Default Color for Countdown Timer
          color: Colors.white,

          // Filling Color for Countdown Timer
          fillColor: Colors.red,

          // Border Thickness of the Countdown Circle
          strokeWidth: 5.0,

          // Text Style for Countdown Text
          textStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 22.0,
              color: Colors.black87,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),

          // true for reverse countdown (max to 0), false for forward countdown (0 to max)
          isReverse: false,

          // Function which will execute when the Countdown Ends
          onComplete: () {
            // Here, do whatever you want
            print('Countdown Ended');
          },
        ))
```